# Rails 5 Could not find the association for join table, test looking for inverse table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 questions about has_many :through relations, and about some errors I don't understand that I'm getting with the setup I'm trying to create.  First I'll describe what I've set up:

I have a Task model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :task_standards
  has_many :standards, through: :task_standards
end
```

and a Standard model

```
class Standard < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :task_standards
  has_many :tasks, through: :task_standards
end
```

I needed a relationship between tasks and standards that also has another field, so I generated a TaskStandard model

```
class TaskStandard < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :standard
end
```

which created a migration `20190704213323_create_task_standards.rb`

```
class CreateTaskStandards < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :task_standards do |t|
      t.belongs_to :task, index: true
      t.belongs_to :standard, index: true
      t.string :level

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I can see the task_standards table in the database

```
                                         Table "public.task_standards"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                   
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------
 id          | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('task_standards_id_seq'::regclass)
 task_id     | bigint                      |           |          | 
 standard_id | bigint                      |           |          | 
 level       | character varying           |           |          | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "task_standards_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_task_standards_on_standard_id" btree (standard_id)
    "index_task_standards_on_task_id" btree (task_id)
```

I ran my tests but I get the error:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "standards_tasks" does not exist`.  I have dropped and created both my test and development environment databases, and rolled back and rerun the migration.

I went to the Rails console and tried to create a Task, and set the task standards to an array of new tasks, but the console gives the error, `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the association :standard_tasks in model Task)` ... and if I try to create a standard and add tasks to it, I get the same, but inverse: `(Could not find the association :task_standards in model Standard)`

My questions are :

1. Why are the tests looking for standards_tasks instead of tasks_standards?
2. How do I create standard.tasks or task.standards in my controller?  Do I have to create a standardTask object?
3. I know the answer to this now... why do I get the `could not find the association :standard_tasks in model Task` in the console I hadn't yet added the `has_many :task_standards` in my standard.rb and task.rb. All I had was the `has_many :standards, through :task_standards` (doh!)

---

Update:
I discovered where the issue with "standards_tasks" in my tests was coming from:  I had an old model generation that had created standards_tasks.yml in the fixtures, and it didn't get removed when I destroyed that migration/model

Comment: It's a bit unclear what issues you still have, you seem to have solved at least some of them?

Comment: Yeah I think I should close this off

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the tests (`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "standards_tasks" does not exist`) was in a residual file left over from a destroyed prior model generation.  There was a `standards_tasks.yml` file in test/fixtures.  When I deleted that .yml file, the tests ran as expected.

The issue with `could not find the association :standard_tasks in model Task` in the console was caused by not including the relation table itself in the models I was relating.  While I had `has_many :tasks, through :task_standards` I hadn't yet added the `has_many :task_standards` in my standard.rb and likewise task.rb.